# Using Knockout with repeated user controls

Tags: javascript, user-controls, knockout.js

I have a web page that contains a list of games. Each game is presented by a user control, that contains a few labels that hold the properties of the game (time, scores, players, etc.). So the same user control is repeated a few times on the page.
The data changes every minute to support live covarage of the game.
I was hoping to use knockout to update all labels in the user control, but since every user control should bind to a different game data, and a user control cannot have its own view model, I dont know what is the best approach to this scenario.
I need something like a dynamic ViewModel and a dynamic data-bind attributes, but I couldnt find any information on the subject.

Comment: can you provide us with what you have so far? Some HTML? some Javascript? And when you say User control, are you talking about ASP.Net Server controls?

Comment: Controls can absolutely have their own view model, and bind to different data. Take a look at the `template` and `foreach` bindings.

Comment: Tyrsius - thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I never knew you could put the User Control markup declaration as a template.

Comment: @Tyrsius why not add that as an answer so we can close the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration of the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) using both `data` and `foreach` with the same template. You can see in the JS that the data is the type, a `game`, but we are dislpaying them separately in the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko if: favoriteGame -->
<h1>Favorite Game</h1>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'gameTemplate', data: favoriteGame }"></div>
<!-- /ko -->

<h1>All Games</h1>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'gameTemplate', foreach: games }"></div>

<script type="text/ko" id="gameTemplate">
<div>
    <span class="gameName" data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: publisher"></span>
    <input data-bind="value: score" />
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.favoriteGame">Favorite</button>
</div>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
var Game = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
    this.publisher = ko.observable(data.publisher || "");
    this.score = ko.observable(data.score || 0);
};

var ViewModel = function(init) {
    var self = this;
    self.favoriteGame = ko.observable();
    self.games = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(init, function(g) {
        return new Game(g);
    }));
};
```

Note that the `click: $parent.favoriteGame` binding selects the favorite game directly. Knockout passes the current context as the first parameter to function bindings, and since observables are functions, this updates the observable directly, without needing a wrapper function.

You can take a look at this in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/tNWvT/1/). Its not perfectly clear what you where after, you don't have any code in your question. I hope this isn't too far off.